# Definir Valor Default @Html.DropDownListFor via Json - ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, json, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou fazendo uma página de marcação de horário utilizando ASP.NET MVC5. O usuário digita os dados da marcação conforme o print abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, caso ocorra algum erro no cadastro da marcação, o controller retorna a model para view com os dados inseridos pelo usuário, utilizando o conceito de model binding, e já traz os campos preenchidos pelo usuário e a mensagem de erro. Conforme o print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que trouxe todos os campos preenchidos, porém menos o campo funcionário. Esse DropDownList eu preencho via Json, ele traz o dropdown preenchido com os funcionários, porém ele sempre vem selecionado o primeiro item da lista, e não o que usuário selecionou. Minha pergunta é: Como faço para depois que preencher a @Html.DropDownListFor eu setar um valor específico que será exibido ao usuário.

O controller que retorna o JSon com a lista de Funcionários é esse:

```
  FuncionariosFiltro = (from ord in Funcionarios
                                                     join detail in listaTurnoFuncionario on ord.Id equals detail.TCAD_PLAN_TRAB_FUNCIONARIO.TCAD_FUNCIONARIOId
                                                     where detail.TCAD_PLAN_TRAB_FUNCIONARIO.DATA_INICIO <= DateTime.Now.Date && detail.TCAD_PLAN_TRAB_FUNCIONARIO.DATA_FIM >= Convert.ToDateTime(Session["DataAgenda"]).Date
                                                     && ord.CODIGO_STATUS.Id == 1 && (listaAusencia.Where(l => l.FUNCIONARIOId == ord.Id).Count()) == 0
                                                     select ord).ToList();

return Json(new SelectList(FuncionariosFiltro, "Id", "NOME"));
```

No código abaixo, estão o dois DropDownList, o primeiro de serviços, que quando selecionado chama o controller acima que retorna a lista de funcionários, que preenche o segundo DropDownList, que é do Funcionários.

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-auto">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.CodigoServico, new SelectList(ViewBag.Servico, "CODIGO", "DESCRICAO"), "Serviço", new Dictionary<string, object>
                                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                                    {"data-toggle", "tooltip"},
                                                                                                                                    {"title","Informe o serviço desejado"},
                                                                                                                                    {"class","form-control" },
                                                                                                                                    {"id","CategoryType" },
                                                                                                                                    {"name","CategoryType" }
                                                                                                                                })
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-auto">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.CodigoFuncionario, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Id", "NOME"),  new Dictionary<string, object>
                                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                                    {"data-toggle", "tooltip"},
                                                                                                                                    {"title","Informe o Funcionário que irá realizar o serviço"},
                                                                                                                                    {"class","form-control" },
                                                                                                                                    {"id","SubCategory" },
                                                                                                                                    {"name","SubCategory" }
                                                                                                                                })

            </div>
```

Quando é selecionado o serviço pelo usuário ele dispara o Java Script Abaixo, que chama o controller que retorna a lista de funcionários e preenche o dropDownList. Acredito que seja nessa função java script que eu deva mexer pra pré-selecionar o valor do dropDownList, porém não sei de qual forma proceder.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#CategoryType").change(function () {

        $("#SubCategory").empty();

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',

            url: '@Url.Action("CarregarFuncionarioVSservico", "ManutencaoAgenda")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: $("#CategoryType").val() },
            success: function (subcategories) {

                $.each(subcategories, function (i, subcategory) {

                    $("#SubCategory").append('<option value="'
                        + subcategory.Value + '">' +
                        subcategory.Text + '</option>');
                });

            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Sub Categories : ' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para setar o DropDownList você tem que informar que o registro está selecionado. No fonte abaixo, troca o `regraParaSelecionar` pela sua logica para validar o funcionário que estava selecionado.

```
$.each(subcategories, function (i, subcategory) {
    if (regraParaSelecionar) {
        $("#SubCategory").append('<option selected="selected" value="' + subcategory.Value + '">' + subcategory.Text + '</option>');
    }
    else {  
        $("#SubCategory").append('<option value="' + subcategory.Value + '">' + subcategory.Text + '</option>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Utilizei o código enviado, e era exatamente o que eu precisava. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @WagnerBarbosaDoNascimento se conseguir marque a resposta como sendo a resposta para a pergunta